# how to show data into a input group after click on a tr row which is populated with mysql data using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am making a pharmacy system in this this system I store client information in mysql database
What I want when user click on addNewOrder.php it shows a input field where user writes the name of the client to search in a database and pull out all its information like name of client , mobile number and address I use ajax to make live search and search result shows below the input field in a table form
I want when user click on a tr which shows in search result all information which show in table form
should be displayed in input field like name should be displayed in name input field and number displayed
in number input field and address should be displayed in address input filed for further processing
below it the code what I try. Help me how I can achieve this

this is my searchClient.php code

```
         <?php

          include ("config/config.php");

           if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
             $searchClient = $_POST['search'];

            $searchStatement = " SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_name LIKE '%$searchClient%'";
            $searchQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $searchStatement);

            echo "
                  <table class='table table-hover'>
                  <tbody>
                 ";
           ?>
               <?php  foreach ($searchQuery as $searchResult){ ?>
              <tr onclick='fill("<?php echo $searchResult['customer_id'];?><br> <?php echo 
              $searchResult['customer_name'];?><br><?php echo $searchResult['customer_number'];?><br> 
              <?php echo $searchResult['customer_address']; ?>")'>
             <th scope="row"><?php echo $searchResult['customer_name']; ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $searchResult['customer_number']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $searchResult['customer_address']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
          }
        }?>
```

and this my html and ajax code

```
          <?php
            include_once ("config/config.php");
               ?>
                <!doctype html>
          <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
           <head>
            <!-- Required meta tags -->
             <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
             <link href="bootstrap/bootstrap-4.5.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
             <link href="fontawesome-free-5.15.1-web/css/all.min.css">
            <link href="site_css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/datatables.min.css"/>
           <title>Add New Order</title>
           </head>
           <body>
           <?php include("config/navBar.php"); ?>

            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                 <div class="card mt-4 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">Search Client</div>
                       <form method="post">

                        <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control js-search" placeholder="Search Client 
                             Here"
                               id="searchClient" name="searchClient">
                        <div class="js-search-result"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card mt-4 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">
                Client Information
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="js-result-name"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
           <?php include("config/scripts.php") ?>

           <script>

           function fill(value){
           $(".js-result-name").html(value);
            $(".js-search-result").hide();
              $(".js-search").val("");
             }

        $(document).ready(function(){
           $(".js-search").keyup(function (){
           var searchItem = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
          //url: "searchExample.php",
          url: "searchClient.php",
          type: "post",
          data : {
              search: searchItem,
          },
          //dataType: "json",
          success: function(data){
              $('.js-search-result').html(data).show();

          }
      });
   });
});
      </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: where are inputs fields in your code?

Comment: this is question how I can show data in input fields I did not add input fields yet the input fields should replace with class name which is js-result-name currently it shows the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `click` event whenever your tr is clicked using this get all datas of `td` & `th` and then add same to your input box using `.val()`. Also, i have use `data-id` you can change your `<tr>` like this : `<tr data-id="<?php echo $searchResult['customer_id'];?>">` and all other datas are already shown inside your trs .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//on click of tr
$(document).on("click", "tbody tr", function() {
  //get all values from th & td
  var name = $(this).find("th").text()
  var phone = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text()
  var address = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text()
  var customer_id = $(this).data('id')
  //add value to inputs..
  $(".js-result-name").val(name)
  $(".js-result-phone").val(phone)
  $(".js-result-address").val(address)
  $(".js-result-id").val(customer_id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--suppose this is shown after search-->
<table border="1px">
  <tr data-id="1">
    <th scope="row">Abc</th>
    <td>438434</td>
    <td>Soemthing.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="2">
    <th scope="row">Abc2</th>
    <td>4384342</td>
    <td>Soemthing2.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="3">
    <th scope="row">Abc3</th>
    <td>4384343</td>
    <td>Soemthing3.</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="card mt-4 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
    <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">
      Client Information
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <input type="text" name="id" class="js-result-id">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="js-result-name">
      <input type="text" name="phone" class="js-result-phone">
      <input type="text" name="address" class="js-result-address">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```